# A mysterious black vertical bar problem (html,domino xpage)

Tags: html, css

I have a problem,<strike>no matter what browser I use</strike>(after tests,I found this problem only exists in IE6, and I guess it may be related to the iframe), a black vertical bar always show up when I open the page at first time,but the problem just occur on some PCs and notebooks,and when I move the browser, the black bar changes or disappears at the meantime.I snaped two screenshots:

[http://vilence.host152.ftp18.cn/pics/p1.jpg http://vilence.host152.ftp18.cn/pics/p1.jpg](http://vilence.host152.ftp18.cn/pics/p1.jpg)

[http://vilence.host152.ftp18.cn/pics/p2.jpg http://vilence.host152.ftp18.cn/pics/p2.jpg](http://vilence.host152.ftp18.cn/pics/p2.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide some HTML and/or CSS?

Comment: The code is too many, and I don't know which parts could help to solve the problem. The both side of that vertical bar are in two cell of a table, and the area of right side is an iframe.
btw:I don't use any filter effect at all,

Comment: After some tests, I found only IE6 exists this problem, Ie7,Ie8 and ff works fine,and when I remove the iframe in right side, all browsers works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the hardware problem first and then check for the borders and border colors         sometimes we fail to manage the div and their alignments specially with complex structure of   the position:abosule or relative or fixed, I frames does i have some kind of things. But   divs does lots of same type mistakes..

do to give wrapper for every div like

```
   <div id="content-wrapper" class="outer-cls wrapper">
     <div id="content" class="inner-cls inner">CONTENT HERE</div>
   </div>
```

this technique make debugging and themeing easy . I was having same type of problem lot of   time. ;)